# vertically centred horizontal navigation

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, vertical-alignment

As a HTML/CSS newbie, I am trying to create a centered horizontal main menu with vertical drop down submenus.
The submenus are supposed to perfectly align with the parent main menu element.
*Cannot attach picture due to lack of reputation points, but have a visualization in case that could help anyone.*

In my current set-up, the submenu items (Directions and Google Maps) are aligned completely to the left and I cannot get them nicely under the main menu item (Location). I believe the solution lies with the absolute/relative positioning of elements, but I cannot figure out how to implement it without destroying the general layout.

Finally, the sub-menu boxes should all have the same width, while the main menu items can vary according to their normal length.

The end result would be similar to [this example](http://csswizardry.com/demos/centred-nav/dropdown.html), unfortunately the code for it gives a 404 error.

This is my HTML:

```css
#nav {
  color: orange;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-width: 1px 0;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline;
}
#nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1ex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
}
#nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}
#nav li ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#nav li ul li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="location.html">Location</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="location.html#directions">Directions</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="location.html#maps">Google Maps</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="pictures.html">Pictures</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="pricesandavailability.html">Prices &amp; Availability</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="generalinfo.html">General Info</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="reservationsandcontact.html">Reservations &amp; Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Apologies for the newbie requests & cheers to all for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent(`#nav li`) must be positioned `relative`ly.

Initially `ul` renders with some `padding`, you should add `padding: 0` to get proper alignment.

```css
#nav {
  color: orange;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
#nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1ex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
}
#nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}
#nav li ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#nav li ul li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="location.html">Location</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="location.html#directions">Directions</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="location.html#maps">Google Maps</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="pictures.html">Pictures</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="pricesandavailability.html">Prices &amp; Availability</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="generalinfo.html">General Info</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="reservationsandcontact.html">Reservations &amp; Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was in the middle of making a jsFiddle but this is your answer that you're lookin for. Here's the jsFiddle anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/ph95ceja/